# Failed to configure Cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm configuring CMake with VS 2010 Express and Geant4, but I have an error below:

```
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/analysis/CMakeLists.txt:30 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/analysis/CMakeLists.txt:30 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/digits_hits/CMakeLists.txt:27 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/digits_hits/CMakeLists.txt:27 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/error_propagation/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/error_propagation/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/event/CMakeLists.txt:22 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/event/CMakeLists.txt:22 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  source/externals/clhep/CMakeLists.txt:229 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  source/externals/clhep/CMakeLists.txt:229 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/externals/expat/CMakeLists.txt:20 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/externals/expat/CMakeLists.txt:20 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/externals/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:20 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/externals/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:20 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/geometry/CMakeLists.txt:28 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/geometry/CMakeLists.txt:28 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/global/CMakeLists.txt:26 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/global/CMakeLists.txt:26 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/graphics_reps/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/graphics_reps/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/intercoms/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/intercoms/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/interfaces/CMakeLists.txt:21 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/interfaces/CMakeLists.txt:21 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/materials/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/materials/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/parameterisations/CMakeLists.txt:19 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/parameterisations/CMakeLists.txt:19 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/particles/CMakeLists.txt:29 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/particles/CMakeLists.txt:29 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/persistency/CMakeLists.txt:35 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/persistency/CMakeLists.txt:35 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/physics_lists/CMakeLists.txt:22 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/physics_lists/CMakeLists.txt:22 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/processes/CMakeLists.txt:36 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/processes/CMakeLists.txt:36 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/readout/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/readout/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/run/CMakeLists.txt:21 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/run/CMakeLists.txt:21 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/track/CMakeLists.txt:21 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/track/CMakeLists.txt:21 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/tracking/CMakeLists.txt:21 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/tracking/CMakeLists.txt:21 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/FukuiRenderer/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/FukuiRenderer/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/HepRep/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/HepRep/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/RayTracer/CMakeLists.txt:25 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/RayTracer/CMakeLists.txt:25 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/Tree/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/Tree/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/VRML/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/VRML/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/XXX/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/XXX/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/gMocren/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/gMocren/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/management/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/management/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:69 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/modeling/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:94 (target_compile_features):
  The compiler feature "cxx_alias_templates" is not known to CXX compiler

  "MSVC"

  version 16.0.40219.1.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4MacroLibraryTargets.cmake:300 (GEANT4_LIBRARY_TARGET)
  source/visualization/modeling/CMakeLists.txt:18 (GEANT4_GLOBAL_LIBRARY_TARGET)


Configuring download of missing dataset G4NDL (4.5)
Configuring download of missing dataset G4EMLOW (6.48)
Configuring download of missing dataset PhotonEvaporation (3.2)
Configuring download of missing dataset RadioactiveDecay (4.3)
Configuring download of missing dataset G4NEUTRONXS (1.4)
Configuring download of missing dataset G4PII (1.3)
Configuring download of missing dataset RealSurface (1.0)
Configuring download of missing dataset G4SAIDDATA (1.1)
Configuring download of missing dataset G4ABLA (3.0)
Configuring download of missing dataset G4ENSDFSTATE (1.2)
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.cmake:440 (message):
  system runtime library file does not exist:
  'MSVC10_REDIST_DIR-NOTFOUND/x86/Microsoft.VC100.CRT/msvcp100.dll'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4CPackBase.cmake:9 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:147 (include)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.cmake:440 (message):
  system runtime library file does not exist:
  'MSVC10_REDIST_DIR-NOTFOUND/x86/Microsoft.VC100.CRT/msvcr100.dll'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/Geant4CPackBase.cmake:9 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:147 (include)


The following Geant4 features are enabled:
GEANT4_BUILD_CXXSTD: Compiling against C++ Standard '11'

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/GEANT4/geant4_10_02_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/GEANT4/geant4_10_02_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Can you give me advice?

Comment: I think this means you need to upgrade your compiler.

Comment: This says Visual Studio 2013 was the first version to support Alias Templates. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your visual studio version is too old, and such does not support all features required for building the project.

Looking at their page, it seems they are building with Visual Studio 2015, so you might give that a try.

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Right answer, **unfortunately, not even "Visual Studio 2017" is fully `C++11` compliant** (I got here while building `Boost`, which's build section only mentions their need for `C++11` compliant compiler, not with what `MSVC` version they tested `Boost`). Microsoft says "Support for C11 and C17 standards is available in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and later", but not tested their claim yet.